# Is there a way to include file in coffee script?

Tags: javascript, include, coffeescript

I'd like to know if there is a way to include a file in a coffee script.
Something like `#include` in C or `require` in PHP...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150455/structuring-coffeescript-code

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about [coffeescript-concat](https://github.com/fairfieldt/coffeescript-concat)?

> **coffeescript-concat** is a utility that preprocesses and concatenates
>   CoffeeScript source files.
>
> It makes it easy to keep your CoffeeScript code in separate units and
>   still run them easily. You can keep your source logically separated
>   without the frustration of putting it all together to run or embed in
>   a web page. Additionally, coffeescript-concat will give you a single
>   sourcefile that will easily compile to a single Javascript file.

Comment: Jason's correct: You need to look at external tools to do this. It's not a feature that's baked into the language.

Comment: I can't recommend coffeescript-concat, check out https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-sprockets-directives instead

Answer (score 20):

If you use coffeescript with node.js (e.g. when using the commandline tool `coffee`) then you can use node's `require()` function exactly as you would for a JS-file.

Say you want to include `included-file.coffee` in `main.coffee`:

In `included-file.coffee`: declare and export objects you want to export

```
someVar = ...
exports.someVar = someVar
```

In `main.coffee` you can then say:

```
someVar = require('included-file.coffee').someVar
```

This gives you clean modularization and avoids namespace conflicts when including external code.

Comment: how do you over come required not being in the browser without using another plugin js file?

Comment: @Lpc_dark: This solution was about node.js on the server. It doesn't work in the browser where node.js is not available, unless you do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081191/could-node-js-run-client-side-in-chrome-with-its-native-client-to-be-released-s (I haven't tried this out myself, though).

Comment: and I found this article is useful to this solution: [Where Does Node.js And Require() Look For Modules?](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm)

Answer (score 4):

### Tl;DR: [Browserify](http://browserify.org/), possibly with a build tool like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)...

### Solutions review

#### Build tool + import pre-processor

If what you want is a single JS file to be run in the browser, I recommend using a build tool like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) (or [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), or [Cake](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/cake.html), or [Mimosa](http://mimosa.io/), or [any other](https://gist.github.com/callumacrae/9231589)) to pre-process your Coffeescript, along with an include/require/import module that will concatenate included files into your compiled output, like one of these:

- [Browserify](http://browserify.org/): probably the rising standard and my personal favourite, lets you to use Node's `exports/require` API in your code, then extracts and concatenates everything required into a browser includable file. Exists for [Grunt](https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify), [Gulp](https://github.com/deepak1556/gulp-browserify), [Mimosa](https://github.com/JonET/mimosa-browserify) and probably most others . To this day I reckon it is probably the best solution if you're after compatibility both Node and the browser (and even otherwise)
- Some Rails Sprocket-like solutions like [grunt-sprockets-directives](https://github.com/Kinvey/grunt-sprockets-directives) or [gulp-include](https://github.com/wiledal/gulp-include) will also work in a consistent way with CSS pre-processors (though those generally have their own importing mechanisms)
- Other solutions include [grunt-includes](https://github.com/vanetix/grunt-includes) or [grunt-import](https://github.com/marcinrosinski/grunt-import)

#### Standalone import pre-processor

If you'd rather avoid the extra-complexity of a build tool, you can use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) stand-alone, or alternatives not based on Node's `require` like [coffeescript-concat](https://github.com/fairfieldt/coffeescript-concat) or [Coffee-Stir](http://beastjavascript.github.io/Coffee-Stir/)

#### [Not recommended] Asynchronous dynamic loading (AJAX + eval)

If you're writing exclusively for the browser and don't mind, or rather really want, your script being spread across several files fetched via AJAX, you can use a myriad of tools like:

- [yepnope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/) or [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/#load)'s .load based on yepnope: Please note that yepnope is now deprecated by its maintainer, who recommend using build tools and concatenation instead of remote loading
- [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)
- [HeadJS](http://headjs.com/)
- [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)'s `$.getScript`
- Vanilla AJAX + eval
- your own implementation of [AMD](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this library I made to solve this same problem coffee-stir
its very simple.
Just type #include and the name of the file that you want to include

```
#include MyBaseClass.coffee
```

For details
http://beastjavascript.github.io/Coffee-Stir/

Comment: Coffee-stir has a several disadvantages: 1)It adds redundant text after processing, because of this you can use it in pipe (or you have to remove the last line someway) 2) It can't directly compile into .JS

Comment: You are right. If I use "require" it includes both of files.

Answer (score 1):

I found that using "gulp-concat" to merge my coffee scripts before processing them did the trick. It can be easily installed to your project with npm.

`npm install gulp-concat`

Then edit your gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
,coffee = require('gulp-coffee')
,concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('coffee', function(){
  gulp.src('src/*.coffee')
    .pipe(concat('app.coffee')
    .pipe(coffee({bare: true}).on('error', gulp.log))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/')
})
```

This is the code I used to concatenate all my coffee scripts before gulp processed it into the final build Javascript. The only issue is the files are processed in alphabetical order. You can explicitly state which file to process to achieve your own file order, but you lose the flexibility of adding dynamic .coffee files.

```
gulp.src(['src/file3.coffee', 'src/file1.coffee', 'src/file2.coffee'])
  .pipe(concat('app.coffee'))
  .pipe(coffee({bare: true}).on('error', gulp.log))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build/')
```

[gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) as of February 25th, 2015 is available at this url.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Cheers! I'm new to contributing here. I'll edit this.

Answer (score 0):

Rails uses sprockets to do this, and this syntax has been adapted to https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-sprockets-directives. Works well for me.