# Coffeescript: Unable to instantiate object of a class in different file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, protractor, ui-testing

I'm unable to instantiate (or call their methods) classes present in other files in my protractor codes in testing. 
Here are my files

Input.coffee

```
   class exports.Input

      @element = null

        constructor: (@type, @selector, @identifier) ->
        if @selector is "id"
          @element = element(By.id(@identifier))
        if @selector is "class"
          @element = element(By.css(@identifier))
        console.log @element

      click: ->
        @element.click()

      putText: (inputText) ->
        @element.sendKeys(inputText)
```

test.coffee

```
describe 'Testing protractor modules', ->
  it 'Testing demo and experimentations', ->
# Initialize all the DOM elements which the suite covers 
    initialize = require('..\\utils\\initialize.coffee').Initialize("https://url.com")    

    inputText = require('..\\utils\\input.coffee').Input("text", "id", "user_email")
    inputPassword = require('..\\utils\\input.coffee').Input("text", "id", "user_password")

    console.log inputText # This is printing undefined
    inputText.putText("analytics@grs.com")
    inputPassword.putText("analytics123")
```

initialize.coffee

```
class exports.Initialize
  constructor: (@url) ->
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true
    browser.get @url
    console.log "Initialize constructor" # This works
```

Error: Cannot read property of undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to include file in coffee script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718121/is-there-a-way-to-include-file-in-coffee-script)

Comment: @Someone No because I'm doing UI testing using protractor where it doesn't make sense to concat my files with a command. Correct me if I'm wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is cause the required CoffeeScript files aren't transpiled to JavaScript. If you include CoffeeScript compiler in your HTML page it'll only automatically compile `<script type="text/coffeescript">` elements at the start.

I'd basically stop using `require` to include CoffeeScript files.

Although there's a utility that concatenates various CoffeeScript files into a single one, here https://github.com/fairfieldt/coffeescript-concat (quoted in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718121/is-there-a-way-to-include-file-in-coffee-script), this is why this is a duplicate question), so you can easily compile the single file to JavaScript.

If you still want something similiar to `require` to load CoffeeScript files you'd need to make an asynchronous or synchronous HTTP request for such file, get the content, then transpile it to JS code.

Synchronous HTTP requests are deprecated, so you can't make something similiar for `require`, you'd need a callback function to be executed later... or too late, after the request has been done and after the CoffeeScript was compiled.

You'll also need to evaluate the compiled CoffeeScript with `Function` or `eval`. `eval` executes the code in the current scope it has been called, while `Function` executes in the global scope.

Example using asynchronous HTTP requests and `eval` to evaluate the compiled CoffeeScript (include the CoffeeScript compiler first):

(Note: this example doesn't avoid a script to cache, this is a bit broad)

```js
function getCoffee(filePath, callback) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
    request.open('get', filePath, true);

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {

            if (request.status === 200) {
                var compiled = CoffeeScript.compile(request.responseText);

                if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                    callback(compiled);
                }
            }
            else {
                /* Handle request error here */
            }
        }
    };

    request.send();
}
```

```coffeescript
getCoffee "script.coffee",
          (compiled) ->
            eval compiled;
```

Note: I don't know the way how your `require` works because I don't know Angular.js, so you may handle the exports manually.