# Distribute cocoa app with meteor.js

Tags: javascript, xcode, cocoa, node.js, meteor

Does anyone know if it is possible (and if so, how) to distribute a cocoa application with meteor.js and rendering it through a webview?

What I mean is that I want to launch a meteor server (or node.js) insied of my cocoa application and then with a cocoa webView show the content of what the meteor server is generating.

So the question is how to get meteor/node to be distributed together with the cocoa application so that the user doesn't have to manually install it.

Comment: Could you give some sort of example? There is no automatic way to convert a cocoa app to a meteor website, but you can display a website within a `UIWebView`

Comment: Now I've updated it a bit!

Comment: I'm afraid that's not (really) possible (unless you fancy writing an interpreter for JavaScript in Objective-C. However, incorporate the mentality of `meteor.js` - create one, reactive site and display the in your WebView. What exactly is it that you want to do with meteor?

Comment: The thing is that I want to use the same code base for a desktop app, and for a web app, but with the difference that the desktop app can access the users's files directly from their harddrive (through node.js). Therefore it would be nice to be able to create a cocoa wrapper for the meteor.js web-app :)

Answer (score 1):

You could embed a compressed archive of the server inside the application package (using copy files build phase of Xcode), and during app startup, unarchive/install/start it possibly using a combination of NSBundle/NSFileManager/NSTask apis. Your app can then view the served pages in a web view using something like http:127.0.0.1:YOUR_PORT/YOUR_APP_DIR.

I am assuming you are not providing your users with a installer (.pkg) since in that case, your installer script would be the take care of the installation part.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty ambitious, but you could try

- https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit
- http://jsapp.us/
- http://browserver.org/
- https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit
- http://iceddev.github.com/blog/2012/11/05/node-js-in-chrome/

Check out [Could Node.js run client side in Chrome with its native client (to be released soon)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081191/could-node-js-run-client-side-in-chrome-with-its-native-client-to-be-released-s) for some of the commentary. Meteor is built on top of node. Mongo I think would be the sticking point.